# URL Pattern For 5 Term Parents Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, uri

I know how to configure the path for 4 or 5 Term Parents Taxonomy.
I have used this code: `[term:vocabulary]/[term:parent:parents-all]/[term:name]`
But this is not works for 5 Term Parents Taxonomy path.. any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `[term:vocabulary]/[term:parents:join:/]/[term:name]`?

Comment: it has the same result.. so what i should do?